# How to call a native Objective-C method from javascript function in a local HTML5 file and vice-versa using native Objective-C method?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, xcode

I want to call a JavaScript function like:

```
- (void)alertMe:(NSString *)msg {
[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
}
```

and

```
function alertMe(msg) {
alert(msg);
}
```

How can I call it using XCode if the HTML file is loaded on a UIWebView in XCode

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [EasyJSWebView](https://github.com/dukeland/EasyJSWebView) to easily implement calling Native **`Objective-C`** method from **`JavaScript`**.
The more convenient way is to implement a class that holds all your methods that your `JS` will call and instantiate that class with your UIWebView Control Object subclass with EasyJSWebView as an argument.

For example:
I created a class `JSInterface` to hold all my native Obj-C methods

I have a custom method

```
- (void)initializeJSInterfaceForWebView:(EasyJSWebView *)webView {
    self.jsInterface.appDelegate = appDelegate;
    self.jsInterface.webView.delegate = self;
    [webView addJavascriptInterfaces:self.jsInterface WithName:@"nativeInterface"];
}
```

that will initialized `EasyJSWebView`.

I instantiate

```
self.jsInterface = [JSInterface initWithView:self];
[self initializeJSInterfaceForWebView:self.webView];
```

For instance, we have a native `Objective-C` method:

```
- (void) printLog:(NSString *)msg {
    NSLog(@"%@", msg);
}
```

To call on the native method from **`JavaScript`** using the `nativeInterface` object name as follows:

```
nativeInterface.printLog("This is only a test.");
```

Comment: This answer is more flexible and I think more appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

Use the delegate method UIWebView

`- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`

implement query string for your javascript function

Answer (score 1):

You may want to implement query string for your JavaScript function e.i:

```
function getQueryString(){ 
var mySearch = window.location.search.substr(1).split("&");

     if (mySearch!="") 
     {
          for(var x=0;x<mySearch.length;x++) {
                // loop to all your query string here
          }

     }
}//end function
```

Or you may also want to use the method

> `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString*)]`

where you may call you local javascript like:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"javascript:myJSFunction()"];
```

Bu this method can only be called within the `webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` and/or when called within `webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType` method the `return` must be `NO`.